# How to format selected columns as percentage - R Kable

Tags: r, kable

I cannot get my kable table to show columns V3 and V4 as percent. Columns V2, V3 and V4 are numeric.

```
moment_table[, c("V1","V2","V3","V4")] %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
    cell_spec(round(x, digits=4), bold = T, color = "white",
              background = spec_color(x, end = 0.9)) }) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c("V3", "V4")), function(x){
    cell_spec(sprintf("%1.2f%%", 100*x)) }) %>%
kable(escape = F, align = "c")
```

I get the error: `Error in 100 * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some columns have strings, convert to `numeric` using `as.numeric()`.

Try running `100*"x"` to understand what is going on.

Comment: hmmm, it seems that you cannot mutate a column more than once, so I mutated each separately

Comment: @Laurence_jj can you include a sample of you data?

Comment: @Laurence_jj you can mutate a column more than once, the problem might be something else